# jquery mouseover() that checks for files in drag and drop?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

Is there any version of jquery's .mouseover() that can be used to check if the user is dragging files to the mouseover state?

The context is that when a user hovers over a div, if they're holding their mouse button to drag something over to it I want to do one thing, if it's just a normal mouseover I want to do another thing.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily is you use jQuery UI. I've made a sample here to demonstrate:

- http://jsfiddle.net/hsTqR/

Mouse-over when not dragging on the `droppable` element will change the font (one effect). If you are dragging the `draggable` and hover over `droppable`, you will see that instead of that the color changes (another effect).

If you don't want to use jQuery UI for this, then you would have to simulate the above yourself:

- Whenever some object (`draggable` in my example above) is dragged, you would need to trigger some flag that you have an object that is being dragged,
- Similar, clear that flag when your `draggable` stops being dragged,
- In your `mouseover` event handlers, have different effects based on the flag - if flag is set, do one thing, if it's cleared, do something else

Hope this helps.